# Fluent NHibernate HASMANY mapping without references

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am a beginner at using Fluent NHibernate.
I am developing a C# application that has to interact with an existing database.Let say I have 2 tables: Items and ItemsList.

```
Items:     ID INT     ItemName VARCHAR(100)
ItemsList: ID INT     ChildItemID INT
```

I've built 2 classes and their mapping:

```
public class Items
{
    public virtual int id {get; set;}
    public virtual string itemName {get; set;}

}

public class ItemsMap : ClassMap<Items>
{
    public ItemsMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.itemsName);
    }
}


public class ItemsList()
{
    public virtual int id {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<Items> childItems {get; set;}

    public ItemsList()
    {
        childItems = new List<Items>();
    }
}

public class ItemsListMap : ClassMap<ItemsList>
{        
    public ItemsListMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        HasMany(x => x.childItems).KeyColumn("childID").Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

And finally, I insert an item in the itemsList and save it all:

```
try
{
    using( ISession session = NH.OpenSession())
    {
        using(ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Items i = New Items()
            i = session.get<Items>(1);

            ItemsList il = new ItemsList();
            il.childID.Add(i);
            session.SaveOrUpdate(il);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }        
}
```

So when I commit, I have a new entry in ItemsList table, but the childID is blank.

Question:

All the examples I see has a reference to ItemsListID in Items table. But I don't want to have this reference since I want the item to be unique in the items table. How can I acheve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NHibernate native way for expressing the unique reference, is:

[5.1.12. one-to-one](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone)

> There are two varieties of one-to-one association:
>
> - primary key associations
> - unique foreign key associations
>
> Primary key associations **don't need** an extra table column; if **two rows are related by the association then the two table rows share the same primary key value**. So if you want two objects to be related by a primary key association, you must make sure that they are assigned the same identifier value!...

Other words, Tables would look like this *(Table `Items` generates the **value** of `ItemID`, table `ItemsList` takes that value and stores it in the `ItemID` )* :

```
Items:     ItemID INT     ItemName VARCHAR(100)
ItemsList: ItemID INT
```

The C# would be *(I changed Items into `Item` and ItemList into `ItemMoreDetails`, because it is not a list anymore)*

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual int ItemId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ItemMoreDetails ItemMoreDetails {get; set; }

public class ItemMoreDetails
{
    public virtual int ItemId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Item Item {get; set;}
```

The mapping would be (in fluent):

```
// Parent side
public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        ...
        HasOne(x => x.ItemMoreDetails).Cascade.All();

// child side
public class ItemMoreDetailsMap: ClassMap<ItemMoreDetails>
{
    public ItemMoreDetailsMap()
    {
        ...
        References(x => x.parent).Unique();
```

See the doc:

#### [HasOne / one-to-one](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#hasone--one-to-one)